# What is the way to update System.Data.Entity dll in .Net?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have `System.Data.Entity version 4.0.0 and my .NET framework is 4.5.2`
I want the next version of system.data.entity. How to update it? In which package it is present? Can we simply update it through nuget package manager?

Comment: The package manager is the only way to install it to begin with. EF is deployed as a separate Nuget Package, not as part of the framework. The *next* version is Entity Framework 6.2 which is *very* different from the version released in 2012

Comment: install .net 4.8 and target your application to .net 4.8 to have latest version.